# Geocoder gem - Displaying nearby other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

Right to the question, i have two models, houses and shops, When i go into my view show, i would like to display not only all nearby houses, but also shops, i am not sure what to put in my controller but at my view it goes something like this for houses, as far for shops if i put the similiar only calling shops, it throws an error as undefined functions for nearbys..

```
#app/views/houses/show.html.erb

<h3>Houses</h3>
<ul>
<% for house in @house.nearbys(10) %>
  <li><%= link_to house.address, house %> (<%= house.distance.round(2) %> km)</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Works great for only one model, but for others... I need your help

Thank you in advance

Comment: lexander K.A. Im trying to use same geocoder gem in my application. But I got error like this: https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/282 Please help me.

Comment: I am not using MongoDB, and I dont even have those lines, in my Location, sorry I am still a begginner at rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/273-geocoder.mp4

Comment: Thank you, but this example only uses one model, i need something similiar but with lots of models

Answer (score 1):

The .near method is a class method, so you can do something like this:

Shop.near(@house.address)

and that will return the shops near the house (assuming that you are geocoding by an attribute/method named "address" for your house model). You can also use the coordinates from @house, and enter how far away from the coordinates you want as the second argument.

Shop.near([@house.latitude, @house.longitude], 20)

will return all shops within 20 miles of the house's geocoordinates.